# What purpose does the Notification Flash/Email setting serve?

Tags: settings, notifications

The Notification Flash/Email setting (Settings > Sound & display > Notification flash > Email) appears to have no influence on the stock mail app or gmail app. So does it serve any purpose?

In the stock mail app, even if Email notifications (Settings > Notification settings > Email notifications) are on, the flash doesn’t occur, regardless of the system wide Notification Flash/Email setting.

In the gmail app, the Email notifications (Settings > Email notifications) setting controls whether the flash occurs or not, regardless of the system wide Notification Flash/Email setting.

Comment: Is this an HTC Sense based ROM?

Comment: Yes it is an HTC Wildfire running Android 2.1 with HTC Sense. Are the Notification Flash settings specific to HTC Sense then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Notification Flash settings are supposed to enable/disable flashing the LED on the front of the handset for events such as receiving an email or SMS.  If your handset has no LED (my HTC Desire does, my ZTE Blade does not) it has no efect but the option is usually still present as it's a stock option.

Comment: That behaviour is what I would expect from the Notification Flash settings, but it doesn’t have any effect on my email apps, as outlined in my question. After FoleyIsGood’s comment, I realise that my use of HTC Sense might cause behaviour in this area that is different from pure Android. I suppose I was looking to get some confirmation that the Notification Flash settings do work as expected for some people, whether they use HTC Sense or not.

Comment: The notification settings in each mail app (GMail & Stock) control whether a notification is made on the pull-down area at the top of the screen.  The one under sound and vision controls only the LED flash.  FWIW, the setting does work on my Sense-based HTC Desire.